# Landscape lock screen CM12.1

Tags: cyanogenmod, screen

My lock screen is always portrait. Is there a way to make it match whatever rotation the phone is in? Weirdly, if I'm in landscape mode and lock my screen a landscape lock screen shows for a second occasionally but always flips to portrait. Can't see anything in CM settings.

Note 4 - CyanogenMod 12.1

Comment: I think in display, you Can tell it what Ange's to rotate to.

Comment: Auto rotate works for the rest of the time, its only the lock screen that snaps to portrait.

Comment: It's possible that the lock screen just doesn't support it. Don't know why, haven't touched CM in a while.

Comment: That was my thought too, but the occasional glitch that shows it briefly in landscape makes me think there's some way to do it. Either that or they should turn that glitch into a feature.

Answer (score 0):

[Ultimate Rotation Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.fameit.rotate) forces any app - even those that don't support a certain orientation - into any orientation. It also supports setting on a per-app basis.

If paid stuff isn't for you, GravityBox should also have such options, though you'll need to also install Xposed framework.

Comment: Ultimate Rotation Control did not work on the lock screen. I think I'm just going to have to download another lock screen app with landscape support.

Comment: It does - you need to choose one of the "forced" rotation options. Optimally, choosing "Forced Auto + Lock Current" in "rotation choices" and uncheck "show notification" will allow it to seamlessly merge with the built-in auto-rotation switch. I've been using this solution since Jelly Bean and it never failed me on any of my devices.

Comment: It worked! Had it set to Auto not Forced Auto. Thanks for the clarification.